# Is there an example for when these for and while loops are not equivalent?

Tags: java, loops

Comparing

```
for (<init stmnt> <boolean expr>; <incr stmnt>) {
   <body statements>
}
```

to

```
<init stmnt>;
while (<boolean expr>) {
   <body statements>
   <incr stmnt>
}
```

Can we find an example for when the above two loops cannot be equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use the `continue;` statement within the loop, you don't get the same effect.

In the for-loop, the continue statement causes the `<incr stmnt>` to be executed. But in your while loop, it will be skipped because it occurred after the `continue;`

Look at the below two loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}

int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
}
```

The for loop will print 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 (with new lines in between).

The while loop will loop forever and never print something.

Comment: good call. need to put `incr statement` in a `finally` clause :)

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is usually used when you need to repeat something until a given condition is true. For example

```
{inputInvalid = true;
while(inputInvalid)
{
    //ask user for input
    invalidInput = checkValidInput();
}
}
```

The for loop is usually used when you need to iterate a given number of times. Here

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ...//do something for a 100 times.
}
```